# recommended connection method for outside clients to connect to JMS queues

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, ejb, glassfish-3, java-ee-5

We have our clients in an extranet based environment that need to connect to our JMS queues. Should they be able to just lookup our queues and connectionFactories in the JNDI space. 
I mean what is the recommended and scalable approach...

Comment: JNDI and JMS are just java APIs. They do not dictate or specify connection methods or protocols, those are completely implementation-specific. Your solution is going to depend heavily on which JMS and appserver implementations you use.

Comment: But there should still be some commonly followed approach..? 
Like how do the JMS clients 'normally' talk to the queues.. while being in an extranet ('trusted') network...

I am not saying JMS/JNDI has to provide a solution for this.. I am just asking for 'a commonly followed solution or industry best practise'  to this usecase ?

Comment: There is no common approach. Each implementation is different.

Comment: we are using GlassFish v3 application server (just a plain JEE5 compliant server with no vendor extensions) - can someone suggest a recommended approach for our extranet based clients to connect to our queues... in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

During initialisation, client applications will need to access a `ConnectionFactory` and `Destination` (the base type for both `Queue` and `Topic`) object. Collectively, such types are called *administered objects*, and the JMS specification states that they should implement the `javax.naming.Referenceable` and `java.io.Serializable` interfaces.

This means you can make administered objects available to clients not only via a naming service but also via other mechanisms. For example, you could serialize the administered objects and store them in files, transmit the serialized objects as attachments to email messages, make `.jso` (Java Serialized Object) files available on a web/FTP server, and so on. Such an approach might be useful if your concern about extranet clients is that they won't know the contact details of your internal naming service.

But this doesn't really answer your question of *which* is the best technology to make administered objects available to JMS clients? A naming service? Serialised-object files on a shared file system? A web or FTP server? A database? The answer is that there isn't a "universally best" way. Some organisations will standardise on using one technology, and other organisations will prefer to use another technology. If you are writing a JMS client that will be used in many organisations, then you could make your client flexible in how it accesses administered objects. You can do this by implementing a method with a signature like the following:

```
public Object importObject(String instructions);
```

The implementation of that method should look at the start of `instructions` to figure out which technology it should use to retrieve an object. For example:

```
obj1 = importObject("naming#path/in/naming/service");
obj2 = importObject("file#path/to/file.jso");
obj3 = importObject("exec#command to execute");
```

(In practice, the instructions should be obtained from, say, a command-line argument or a configuration file rather than being hard-coded into an application.)

The `"exec#..."` variant shown above will make it possible to execute an arbitrary shell command that can retrieve a `.jso` file from a web or FTP server (perhaps using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)), a database or whatever is most convenient for the user. Years ago, I wrote a similar-ish type of utility function for another middleware technology (CORBA), and the flexibility it offered turned out to be *very* useful. You can read a bit about my CORBA utility function [here](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-utilities/importing-and-exporting-object-references.html).

Another issue to be aware of (and one that @skaffman mentioned in a comment) is that although the JMS specification defines an API, it does *not* define an on-the-wire protocol. Because of this, there is typically no interoperability between different JMS products. So, if your company-internal JMS applications are built with product X, then the company-external JMS clients will also need to be built with product X. Having said that, some vendors might sell a "bridge" that can accept incoming messages via the on-the-wire protocol used by product X and then retransmit the messages using the on-the-wire protocol of product Y. That is one way to provide interoperability between different JMS products.

Disclaimer: don't let the verbosity of this answer fool you into thinking that I am a JMS expert. I actually have very limited experience of using JMS, so if somebody adds a comment saying that my advice is flawed, then they are probably right.